# how redirect from https to http

Tags: http, redirect, https

I need to redirect from https to http
this is my .haccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is an HTTP to HTTPS redirect, so you just need to reverse the logic:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

(I've also simplified the regex `^(.*)$` to `^`.)

You do, however, still need to have a valid SSL cert installed on your server for the redirect to be effective, as otherwise the user-agent won't even reach your server to run your code.

And... redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP in the first place doesn't make a whole lot of sense in 2019.

Comment: Thanks , but i did it